# Can I "merge" a Java Edition and a Bedrock Edition account on a Minecraft Geyser server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I'm making a server for my friends and myself, and I can't currently play on my computer, so I've added Geyser to my server so I can play on my Nintendo Switch. The problem is, the account on my Switch and the account on anything else I play Minecraft on is different. I was wondering if there was a plugin or any way to "merge" these accounts server side, that can keep the inventories, status effects, amount of hearts, and position synced between these accounts. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a built-in geyser feature, you can just do `/linkaccount <Bedrock User Without Prefix>` while logged into the Java account. (Source: [bukkit forum](https://bukkit.org/threads/a-plugin-to-combine-2-accounts-into-1.490517/))

You will need Floodgate installed along with Geyser in order for this to work.

This will make the two accounts be linked on *every* server using Geyser with Floodgate to enable Java+Bedrock play.